# Free (libre) video hosting platform

Tags: video, hosted

I'm looking for a video hosting platform with the following characteristics:

- Can upload under a free ([as in libre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software/)) format
- Convenient HTML5 player
- Free (libre) JavaScript, if JS is used to help serving the content
- Streams under a free (libre) format
- No tracking, no ads
- Anynomous viewing
- Free software

Hey, this looks like **YouTube**, only in better. But I didn't say it must be free (as in gratis) for the uploader however.

1. Does this this golden goose exist?
2. If not, and if someone was to implement it, what would be the chance of success of being finacialy sound, that is getting enough financial revenue (pay plan for uploaders, donators, …) to balance the costs?

Comment: On Meta: [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/675/60)

Comment: Topic rephrased

Comment: So you looking for something you can host yourself, right?

Comment: Correct. Me, or anybody else actually.

Comment: @youri Check this out : https://streamable.com/

Free to upload, No tracking, No ads, Anonymous viewing, Anonymous upload.

Dont know if this what you are looking for or I din't understand your question corerctly. :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be free as in "libre" as required, but rather merely free as in "gratis".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Peertube** https://joinpeertube.org is a free (no charge and libre) open source software developped by the Framasoft Association in France (framasoft.org). You can install it to run your own server and run your own video platform. The idea behind Peertube is decentralized video hosting, where instances cooperate in a peer to peer way.

If you don't want to install your own peertube instance and prefer simply uploading videos to an existing platform, you can use **Framatube** https://framatube.org, which is Framasoft's peertube instance.

I cannot guarantee that Peertube will meet all your requirements, but as its code is open source, your can edit and adapt it.

Comment: Framatube signup is closed at the moment. Went for pe.ertu.be.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the feedback.